# Droid turbo radio off when no signal happen, then can't turn radio back on

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, device-firmware, cellular-radio, gsm, radio-firmware

I just bought Droid Turbo (XT1225) from ebay, everything works fine except the radio, when the phone receive no signal for example in a lift, radio will turn off by itself and can't turn back on.

The unit Bootloader is unlock before sent to me, I flashed latest stock rom and in theory everything should be fresh.

So when radio was force off, I try to turn back on using:

```
*#*#4636#*#*
```

hidden menu, then run logcat -b radio, here is the result

```
D/RilRequest( 1668): [4363]< RADIO_POWER error: com.android.internal.telephony.C
ommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE ret=
D/GsmSST  ( 1668): [GsmSST] 0mDeviceShuttingDown = false
D/GsmSST  ( 1668): [GsmSST] 0mDesiredPowerState = true
D/GsmSST  ( 1668): [GsmSST] 0getRadioState = RADIO_OFF
D/GsmSST  ( 1668): [GsmSST] 0mPowerOffDelayNeed = true
D/GsmSST  ( 1668): [GsmSST] 0mAlarmSwitch = false
D/RILJ    ( 1668): [4364]> RADIO_POWER on [SUB0]
D/RILC    (  341): SOCKET RIL_SOCKET_1 REQUEST: RADIO_POWER length:16
D/RILC    (  341): RequestComplete, RIL_SOCKET_1
E/RILC    (  341): Send Response to RIL_SOCKET_1
D/RilRequest( 1668): [4364]< RADIO_POWER error: com.android.internal.telephony.C
ommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE ret=
```

anyone know what happen?