# Cellular radio dead? No carrier signal, "No service", no mobile networks

Tags: cellular-radio, network-signal, motorola-moto-g-4g

I own a Motorola Moto G 4G (XT1040). Original stock ROM, Android 5.1,  unlocked bootloader, custom TeamWin recovery, rooted. I only install apps from Google Play, F-Droid or trusted sources.

Last week, a strange issue appeared out of the blue -- I haven't flashed any new roms, recoveries, nothing out of the ordinary, just my normal daily usage like the last entire year. Until then, I had been using the same retail stock ROM it came from factory, without ever flashing any other ROMs.

(I have had this very same issue before once, with exactly the same symptoms, but I can't remember what I did in order to fix it - however the fact I was able to fix it could mean it's not a hardware issue. Maybe. Who knows).

The mobile signal icon started displaying zero bars, and a "no service" message:

[image]

I can't make or receive any calls, or use mobile data, despite a "G" icon that, I think, indicates some sort of data connectivity.

## I've already tried:

- Enabling and disabling the airplane mode,
- Rebooting the device,
- Changing the "preferred network mode" to either 2G, 3G or 4G,
- A factory reset,
- Installing CyanogenMod 13.0 latest snapshot,
- Restoring a known good TeamWin full backup (which includes the modem partition)

I've performed `adb logcat -b radio -v time -d` and it includes the following line:

```
12-13 03:42:01.520 D/RilRequest( 1653): [3660]< RADIO_POWER error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE ret=
```

I'd include the entire log here but it's a 300 KB file and I'm not sure how do I anonymize it properly.

So far I'm considering:

1. A hardware issue;
2. <del>A bad SIM card</del> - My SIM card works on another phone;
3. <del>A blacklisted IMEI (**very** unlikely)</del> - according to [random sites](http://www.imeipro.info), there's no block.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132863/my-phone-is-not-connecting-to-the-cell-network-no-service

Comment: My guess would be hardware issue. I'm having a similar problem with my D855.

Comment: Also related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130744/droid-turbo-radio-off-when-no-signal-happen-then-cant-turn-radio-back-on?rq=1

Comment: Try other sim card and see what happens. Also try to flash some other rom, maybe baseband doesn't fit..? Wait the signal dissapeared for no reason, did you done update or such?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Yes, the signal disappeared for no reason at all; at least that I know if. I had been using the same retail stock ROM it came from factory. How could the baseband *suddenly* "not fit"? I have no other SIM cards available, will buy one and test.

Comment: Well I assumed that baseband doesn't fit because you wrote that you have twrp so I tought that you maybe use custom rom. Well if other sim doesn't work either, you can try custom rom. Or less likely maybe sim is dirty or doesn't fit well so try cleaning it with earser or any rubber.

Comment: Oddly, one fix for this on Moto devices is to reflash the radio stack, and if that fails flashing of the full factory image via fastboot often corrects this problem. If you have the latest stock firmware image that matches your devices current ROM, extract NON-HLOS.bin and fsg.mbn and copy them to your fastboot directory, and enter in order  
`fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin` `fastboot erase modemst1` `fastboot erase modemst2` `fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn`
and reboot and test again.